# Install a source RPM from Fedora's rpms

Tags: centos, fedora, yum, rpm, dnf

I found a great package on [Fedora Package Sources](https://src.fedoraproject.org/projects/rpms/%2A). It is hosted as source codes.

The specific package is [Syncthing](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/syncthing), whose official website provides an rpm binary download. But I would like the installation to support automatic update upon `yum update`. So I figured I might just add the repository to `yum` and let `yum` install it from source, so that when later the package is updated, `yum` can recognize and update it. But I could not find how to achieve this despite a thorough Googling. Can any one shed some light for me? Thanks!

Comment: When an RPM is installed via `yum`, does it tell `yum` how to update itself? If so, when a new release comes, will `yum` update it when `yum update` is called?

Comment: Syncthing does not seem to offer RPM packages or a yum repo to do that: https://github.com/syncthing/syncthing/issues/2721

Comment: For what distribution?! syncthing is already in Fedora. You don't need a separate repository.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I was trying to install on CentOS 7. I assumed the installation steps would be pretty much identical. Now it seems that’s not the case?

Comment: Hm. Well, it's not in EPEL. I would contact the Fedora package maintainer and ask him if he can also provide it for EPEL.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks! Would that be the Syncthing team or the Fedora rpms team?

Comment: As I said, the Fedora package maintainer.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Got it! I’ll contact them.